# User Logging in getting redirected to index.php

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, authentication

NOTE: First I am using PHP, HTML, CSS, MySQL (Database), also using Dreamweaver 6 to edit all my code in.

Ok, So for my final year project I am creating a E-Attendance Tracking and Monitoring System. I am having great difficulties with creating logins for multiple users. The three users for this system are STAFF, PARENTS & STUDENTS. For this, I am focusing on STAFF

OK so I have...

1. staff_register.php
2. staff_verify.php
3. staff_login.php
4. staff_home.php

So when a staff wants to sign up they must register first. So I have a form which when submitted writes to the database perfectly. student_register.php posts to student_verify.php, where in this an activation email gets sent to the user requiring them to verify themselves (Click on the Link). Once the user verifys, they become a active user. Then they proceed to the LOG IN page. When the user enters their details, I get redirected back to index.php where in my code I specifically state to get redirected to staff_home.php Below I am going to provide some code:

This is staff_login.php:

```
             <?php include_once("scripts/global.php");
              $message = '';
               ` `if(isset($_POST['email'])){
           $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $remember = $_POST['remember'];  `

//error handeling
if( (!$email) || (!$pass) ){
    $message = 'please insert both fields'; 
}else{
    //secure the data
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $pass = sha1($pass);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE email='$email'
          AND   password='$pass' LIMIT 1") or die("Could not check member");    
    $count_query = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count_query == 0){
        $message = 'The infomation you entered was incorrect';  
    }else{
        //start the sessions
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $username = $row['username'];
            $id = $row['id'];   
        }
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

        if($remember == "yes"){
            //create the cookies 
            setcookie("id_cookie", $id, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
            setcookie("pass_cookie", $pass, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
        }

        header("Location: staff_home.php");

    }

}
```

The PHP Script for index.php is

```
 <?php include_once("scripts/global.php");
    if ($logged == 1) {
      header("Location: staff_home.php");
      exit; 
    }
 ?>
```

I put staff_home.php in the index because as I kept getting redirected to index.php I put the code at the top in hope that it just redirects me to staff_home.php

The PHP Script for staff_home.php is

```
 <?php include_once("scripts/global.php");
    if ($logged == 0) {
      header("Location:staff_home.php");
      exit();
    }
 ?>
```

I suspect that maybe I have to assign users roles, which I have not done.

So what I want is staff to login and get redirected to staff_home.php , student to login and get redirected to student_home and parents to login and get redirected to parent_home.

I been trying to practise PHP for a few months, but the littlest of errors really bug me lol. I am praying someone can help me ! this might seem like a minor error(s) but I would be foreever greatful for any tips and advice on how to improve my code and get it to function. I will check back to see if anyone responds, and also my email is jmudhar90@hotmail.co.uk.

Regards People

Comment: Do you have code in staff_home.php that redirects to index.php if the user tries to access the page but isn't logged in?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Do you have redundant login pages for staff, parent, and student?  If so just have each of those login pages direct to the proper home page like you have done for the staff login page.

Comment: How do you know in the database whether the person is a student, staff or parent?

Comment: @MattCain yes the inital redirection was to index.php  , I just changed it to see otherwise, I put it back to index.php and I get redirected to index.php when I Log in.

Comment: @HanletEscaño in my database I have 3 different tables: Staff, Parent and Student,  I have 3 registration Forms 1 for Staff, 1 for Parent and 1 for Student and also 3 separate logins for them.

Comment: Not in my place to say what you need, but maybe you do need roles after all, in that way you will just need one registration table, and one select for role selection, in the user table you include the roleId, and then you know the role for every user easier...

Comment: @MikeBrant I have the same logins for staff, parent and student , and within each code all that differs is to SELECT * FROM XXXX where email='$email' AND password='$pass' LIMIT 1") or die("Could not check member"); XXXX being Student, Staff or Parent

Comment: @HanletEscaño I was suspecting so do you know any good websites where I can learn how to do roles , or videos , anything :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `session_start()` in your code at any point. You need to call `session_start()` before you can use sessions in a page.

Comment: Ok I put session_start(); on staff_home and have changed the redirection on the staff_home.php to index.php still getting redirected to index.php